# Pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

**PAGINATION SETUP FOR WP_QUERY**

How should I setup pagination in this WP_QUERY for my website.I want only 6 posts in a page.

In my wordpress site I set front-page display as a latest posts instead of particular page.

```
  <div class="row child-section">
            <?php

               /**************************************
               *  Generating multiple posts
               *************************************/

               $args = array(
                   'type' => 'post',
                   'posts_per_page' => 6,
                   'offset' => 1
               );

               $query = new WP_Query($args);

               if($query->have_posts()):
                 while($query->have_posts()):
                    $query->the_post();
            ?>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 other-post clearfix">

                <div class="featured-img">
                   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <h1 class="post-heading">
                <?php
                  $title = wp_trim_words(get_the_title(),3," .. ");
                  echo $title;
                ?>
              </h1>
                <p class="small-desc">
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                <p>
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-btn">READ MORE</a>
            </div>

            <?php
          endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;
            ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

this particular code echo out the paginate_links there are more arguments available for this you can look into [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Answer (score 0):

```
/********function.php*******/
    function wp_custom_pagination() {

global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

$pages = paginate_links( array(

        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),

        'format' => '?paged=%#%',

        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),

        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,

        'prev_next'    => True,

        'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),

        'next_text'    => __('Next »'),

        'type'  => 'array'

    ) );

    if( is_array( $pages ) ) {

        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');

        echo '<div id="pagination"><ul class="page-numbers">';

        echo '<li id="page_num"><span>'. $paged . ' of ' . $wp_query->max_num_pages .'</span></li>';

        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {

                echo "<li id='page_num'>$page</li>";

        }

       echo '</ul></div>';

    }

}
```

/*************************************/

```
          <?php

                     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                     query_posts("posts_per_page=6&order=DESC&paged=$paged"); 

                     if(have_posts())
                        { 
                            while(have_posts())
                            { 
                                the_post();
                    ?>

                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 other-post clearfix">

            <div class="featured-img">
               <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <h1 class="post-heading">
            <?php
              $title = wp_trim_words(get_the_title(),3," .. ");
              echo $title;
            ?>
          </h1>
            <p class="small-desc">
                <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
            <p>
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-btn">READ MORE</a>
        </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                 <div class="pagination"><?php  wp_custom_pagination(); ?>        </div>

             <?php        } wp_reset_query();

                               ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php pagination

```
    global $wpdb;
$db_table_name=(isset($_GET['browse'])!='' && isset($_GET['page'])=='wp_db_admin')?$_GET['browse']:'';
$quer = "select * from ".$_GET["browse"];
$res= $wpdb->get_results($quer);

$results_per_page = 25;
$count_result = "select count(*) from ". $_GET["browse"];
$result_number = $wpdb->get_var($count_result);
 $number_of_pages = ceil ( $result_number/$results_per_page);
 if(!isset($_GET['pagina'])){
     $pagina=1;
 }else{
     $pagina= $_GET['pagina'];
 }
 $this_page_result_first =  ($pagina-1)*$results_per_page;
 $pageQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_name." LIMIT ".$this_page_result_first.",". $results_per_page; 
 $resPageQuery = $wpdb->get_results($pageQuery);
```